# How to represent the product of multiplication instructions in RISCV?

Tags: assembly, riscv, instruction-set

In RISCV, we have `mul t1, s1, s2` and `mulh t2, s1, s2` instructions, which store the lower 32-bits of the product and upper 32-bits of the product respectively. If I need to use the product, should I do `add t0, t2, t1`?

Thank you!

Comment: You cant. If you multiply two 32 bits numbers, the result requires 64 bits to be coded and the real value of the multiplication is t1+2^32*t2.  You must use two 32 bits registers to store the result. Except if you are certain that the result can be stored in 32 bits, in which case, the use of `mulh`  is useless.

Comment: @AlainMerigot, your comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Just as an example using 4 bits instead of 32 bits.
The highest possible multiplication with signed integers is 0111 (7) * 0111 (7) resulting in 110001 (49). So no matter how you twist it, you can not display the result in just 4 bits. Commonly its said that you need double the bits after a multiplication. That is  also why there are also two multiply operations in Risc-V.

So to conclude. You must use two 32 bit registers. Except if you are certain that the result will not overflow the 32 bits. Then you can just use the mul operation without using mulh at all.

Comment: Or if you want to truncate the result to 32-bit, like in C where operations on `unsigned`, including `*`, produce an `unsigned` result.  Then you also just do the low 32 bits, instead of widening to 64 and doing extended-precision add.

Answer (score -1):

If both the high and low bits of the same product
are required, then the recommended code sequence is: MULH[[S]U] rdh, rs1, rs2; MUL rdl, rs1,
rs2 (source register speciers must be in same order and rdh cannot be the same as rs1 or rs2).
Microarchitectures can then fuse these into a single multiply operation instead of performing two
separate multiplies.
MULW is only valid for RV64, and multiplies the lower 32 bits of the source registers, placing the
sign-extension of the lower 32 bits of the result into the destination register. MUL can be used to
obtain the upper 32 bits of the 64-bit product, but signed arguments must be proper 32-bit signed
values, whereas unsigned arguments must have their upper 32 bits clear.

Page 35/36 of RiscV Istruction Set Manual at this link:
https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf